# If we use lot of plugins in App, Is there any chance to slow down the app in Flutter?

Tags: flutter

Am new here.

If we use lot of plugins in App, Is there any effect to slow down the application in Flutter?

Comment: It depends on what kinds of plugins you use.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

many aspects to consider:

1. quality of package
2. size of package
3. content of package (whether contains lots of animations)

Comment: How can we know Size of Package?

Comment: you will know when you build your app, increasing in size of your app

Comment: ok. Thank you Mr. Jim Chiu